# Variable name for PHP associative array index

Tags: php, arrays

I wish to create an associative array where the index is defined by a variable.

```
array($index_name => $foo)
```

but I can't determine the correct syntax.  How do I do this?

-- Geoff

Comment: if the variable is pre-defined, what you wrote should work

Comment: What you have above will work. Please post your actual code in context, with any errors received so we can help you through it.

Comment: You may be able to do this with a variable variable, or perhaps a nested array. Both would be quite a bit slower, though, unless you are already using it elsewhere.

Comment: @trysis: as 2 people already stated, this is just possible, and the syntax in the question is already correct. Don't confuse it with variable variables, as they aren't needed, _and_ variable variables are  best used as little as possible.

Comment: Clearly I'm doing something else wrong.  My code is:  
`
    echo ("$json_data_index $json_data\n");  
    print json_encode(array("err"=>$json_err,   "err_text"=>$json_err_text, 
    $json_data_index >= $json_data), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);  

`
and the result that I get is:  
CI Array  
{"err":0,"err_text":"","0":false}

Comment: My mistake was incredibly stupid. I've been staring at the code for hours and never noted that I had ">=" instead of "=>".  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
  $index_name=0;
  $foo='abc';
  $data=array($index_name => $foo);
  print_r($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct e.g.

```
<?php

$key = 'test';
$arr = array ($key => 'val');

print_r ($arr);
```

Outputs

> Array ( [test] => val )

You can also set array keys in other way -

```
<?php

$array = [$key => $val]; # PHP 5.4 short-syntax
$array[$key] = $val; # Square bracket syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote is completely valid, you can also try (with a defined $index_name)

```
$data[$index_name] = $foo;
```